# Prophet Output formatting in R

Tags: r, facebook-prophet

I am trying to do forecasting using Prophet in **R** using list for multiple items. I am able to get output but when I export to CSV it should be neater and cleaner. Want the output to have date(ds) in one column, Products in 2nd column and values(yhat in 3rd column)

```
tb=as_tibble(data_input)
tslist <- tb %>%   gather("type", "y", -ds) %>% split(.$type)
tslist <- lapply(tslist, function(x) { x["type"] <- NULL; x })
maplist <- map(tslist, prophet)
futurelist <- map(maplist, make_future_dataframe,  periods = 12, freq = 'month')
forecast <- map2(maplist, futurelist, predict)
write.csv(forecast,"Output_Prophet.csv")
```

Any leads to the above code which can provide output in below format.

```
Ds            Product    Yhat
01/01/2017    A          8
01/02/2017    A          9
01/01/2017    B          14
01/02/2017    B          18
```

My current output looks like below format:

[image: Output Prophet]

Comment: Please make your question reproducible. It should have data and code necessary to produce the desired output.

Comment: Can you share the output of `dput(head(forecast))`? I'm not sure what form of output your existing code produces.

Comment: hello @JonSpring just edited my post to show the current output in form of link. Thanks

Comment: Could you please paste the text of `dput(head(forecast))` into your question? A picture doesn't tell us the data formats and would require a lot of unnecessary typing for anyone else to try to use.

Comment: It looks like you could use `tidyr::gather` and `tidyr::separate` to bring the columns into longer format with separate fields for Product and [which statistic]. Then you'd just filter for Yhat.